# Problema con creación de clases java spring boot en IntelliJ Community

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Compre un ordenador ya que el que tenía se malogró, le instalé Java 17 y luego el IntelliJ la cuestión es es quería practicar un poco de lo que voy aprendiendo. Pero me doy con la sorpresa que no me deja crear clases Java.
IMPORTANTE: El proyecto lo cree con Spring Initializr de la web y lo arrastré en IntelliJ.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]